# replace does not work on temporary file

Tags: node.js, replace, fs

I'm using the [replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace) module from NPM successfully (see the first example). However, I want to keep the original file and process a new (temporary) file that is a copy of it. Here is what I tried:

**Works:**

```
var replace = require("replace");
replace({
    regex: "foo",
    replacement: "bar",
    paths: [path_in],
    recursive: true,
    silent: true,
});
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
var replace = require("replace");
var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream(path_in).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path_temp));
replace({
    regex: "foo",
    replacement: "bar",
    paths: [path_temp],
    recursive: true,
    silent: true,
});
```

Do I need to close the `pipe()`? Not sure what to do here..

Thanks,

**Edit:** This GitHub [issue](https://github.com/harthur/replace/issues/58) is related.

Comment: For starters, you don't wait for the `.pipe()` to finish before trying to use its result.

Comment: @jfriend00 So my code looks correct to you too, right? :D

Comment: I don't know anything about the `replace()` library so I have no idea about that.  I just know you can't use the results of a file that hasn't been written yet because you aren't waiting for the file copy to finish.

Comment: Oh, OK, I misunderstood your comment. So how do I wait for it to finish? Is there a callback for `pipe()`?

Comment: I'd suggest you read some of the doc for `.pipe()`.  It returns the desination stream.  And, on that destination stream, you can listen for the `close` and `error` events to know when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.pipe()` is asynchronous so you need to wait for the `.pipe()` to finish before trying to use the destination file.  Since `.pipe()` returns the destination stream, you can listen for the `close` or `error` events to know when it's done:

```
var replace = require("replace");
var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream(path_in).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path_temp)).on('close', function() {
    replace({
        regex: "foo",
        replacement: "bar",
        paths: [path_temp],
        recursive: true,
        silent: true,
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
    // error occurred with the .pipe()
});
```